# voice command not accept in google smart home

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I am developing Smart Home in **Google Home**

After sync devices in google home. everything working fine with Google Home Application(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app&hl=en)

But when I access through voice command(okay google, turn on/off all lights/ ) then it says device not available.

If the device is not available then it should also not work from GUI of google home application. but it's work.

Comment: Check your stackdriver logs for your action (console.cloud.google.com > Stackdriver) - there may be more information available there regarding the particular error occurring, such as a malformed response, which will help you debug this issue.

Comment: Yes there was error  log regarding below error

failed with code: OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE ( "SMART_HOME_QUERY" )
Agent responded empty JSON.( "SMART_HOME_QUERY" )
failed with code: BACKEND_FAILURE ( "SMART_HOME_EXECUTE" ).

But this error not comes every time.

Comment: Seems like you may be sending a bad response back but you are getting requests correctly.

Comment: nope, it's working perfectly from the GUI of Google Home Application. The checked response also's same as google smart home action documents.

Comment: Created same project on another account, it&amp;#39;s working perfectly.
Issue from Google Assistance